# Multiple Where Conditions In Vba ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Please help me with this code.

If the date or the ID field is changed then the records in the subform based on the ID and Date ID deletes the records in the main table but the code works only with the first criteria, with `AND` it doesn't:

```
Private Sub txtDate_AfterUpdate()
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM TableIntensiveAndContinuationPhase WHERE PatientID = " & Me!FrmIntContPhasesubform.Form!PatientID AND PatientDate = " & Me!FrmIntContPhasesubform.Form!PatientDate, dbFailOnError
        'Requery the subform to avoid displaying "DELETED" for the deleted records
        Forms!FrmIntContPhase![FrmIntContPhasesubform].Requery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a few quotation marks in your SQL and thats giving you an error.

```
Private Sub txtDate_AfterUpdate()
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM TableIntensiveAndContinuationPhase WHERE ((PatientID = " & Me!FrmIntContPhasesubform.Form!PatientID & ") AND (PatientDate = #" & Format(CDate(Me!FrmIntContPhasesubform.Form!PatientDate),"mm/dd/yyyy") & "#))", dbFailOnError
```

Comment: Hi Tahmeed thanks but the command is not deleting the records based on ID and Date combination of the patient. When I use only the ID it deletes all the records of that patricular patient ID but I want to delete based on ID and date so that I won't delete whole record of that patient. Thank you please help

Comment: Hmm. I see. Maybe try with brackets around the Where statement e.g. above

Or use the DoCmd.RunSQL method instead of CurrentDb.Execute.

Comment: Also, and this is a long shot, maybe the formatting of the date is messing up something. I know that in SQL usually they want # symbols surrounding the date, and the date written in "mm/dd/yyyy" format, so i've gone ahead and written that code for you. See if that works.

Comment: Thank you Tahmeed your a genius. It worked!!! Is there a way I can messege you directly in stackoverflow for future questions? I am new member of stakoverflow.

Comment: I'm quite new as well. I don't believe there is any way to PM on this website. Feel free to contact me on my email address: tahmeed.nabi@phoenixonline.com.au

Comment: Also, don't forget to mark this question as answered :)